# Yet another LNK2005 error "method already defined in library..."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I converted a VS2005 project to VS2010 and is I am stumped on a LNK2005 error introduced in the conversion to 2010.

```
3>      Searching C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\nafxcwd.lib:
3>nafxcwd.lib(viewcmn.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual struct AFX_MSGMAP const * __thiscall CListView::GetMessageMap(void)const " (?GetMessageMap@CListView@@MBEPBUAFX_MSGMAP@@XZ) 
  already defined in uafxcwd.lib(viewcmn.obj)
```

I have read extensively on the various causes and verified that all libraries are consistent as far as debug\release and runtime libraries plus (I believe) MFC linking before the CRT libraries (although I did not expect these to change after converting to 2010.)

I suspect the problem is the project linking a Unicode library with non-Unicode libraries? The output says a method in 'nafxcwd.lib' has already been defined in 'uafxcwd.lib'.  If this really is the problem then I am not sure why it was introduced after converting to 2010 and what is the safe resolution? I am a little reluctant to just Ignore one of the libraries and hope for the best at runtime.  The Unicode library must remain Unicode and the non-Unicode libraries must remain non-Unicode, it used to be okay in 2005 but not in 2010.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to see how you got away with it in VS2005.  Look for a /nodefaultlib squirreled away somewhere in the 2005 project.

Comment: Is 2010 defaulting the character set to Unicode (and automatically trying to link the Unicode libraries), while 2005 defaulted to MBCS, and your project explicitly links the non-Unicode libraries, leading to the conflict?

Comment: I double checked but did not find any /nodefaultlib settings or projects that did not explicitly state Unicode or MBCS settings. Thanks for the suggestions.